# "È partita una tirata": uso di "partire" e di "tirata"

Tags: word-meaning, word-usage

Un po' per caso, mi sono imbattuta in  questo [sito web](https://www.globalist.it/culture/2016/10/31/a-teatro-tra-le-scosse-le-ultime-perfidie-del-cavalier-serpente-207500.html) in cui si fa una critica di uno spettacolo teatrale basato sul romanzo *Ragazzi di vita*, di Pier Paolo Pasolini. Anni fa ascoltai la lettura di questo romanzo fatta da Massimo Popolizio, il regista dello spettacolo, nel programma "Ad alta voce" di RAI radio 3 e mi piacque, per cui ho avuto curiosità di leggere il testo. Poi, tutto quello che si spiega del lampadario del teatro l'ho trovato divertente.

Questa frase del testo ha attirato la mia attenzione:

> Nel senso che è partita una tirata, senza intervallo, di circa due ore di una enunciazione urlata, ma urlata da fare male alle orecchie, piena di "mortacci tua", "stronzi", "cazzi", eccetera, decisamente esagerati come carico, anche se rigorosamente (ci hanno giurato) fedeli come numero e distribuzione a quelli del testo di Pasolini.<sup>1</sup>

Per il termine "tirata" ho trovato questa [definizione sul vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/tirata):

> Nel linguaggio teatrale, lungo discorso che un personaggio fa sulla scena, senza che altri interloquisca e, in partic., nella commedia dell’arte, quel soliloquio che illustra il carattere di uno dei personaggi e le vicende cui partecipa; per estens., fuori del teatro, lungo discorso, soprattutto se di tono polemico o di disapprovazione: *il presidente ha fatto una t. contro il direttore*; *il suo intervento alla Camera è stato tutto una t. contro il governo*.

Tuttavia, siccome ho letto il romanzo e, a quanto pare, c'erano [parecchi attori](http://www.teatrodiroma.net/doc/6448/ragazzi-di-vita), non credo che la frase si riferisca a un monologo di circa due ore. Allora, mi chiedo: "tirata" può avere un senso leggermente diverso da quello spiegato dal Treccani? E si tratta di qualcosa di inventato dall'autore del testo oppure si usa con certa frequenza anche in questo modo?

Per quanto riguarda "partire", ho visto, sempre sul [vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/partire), che ha questo significato:

> Avere (o dare) inizio: *il lavoro è partito male*; *è ora di p. con questa iniziativa*; *a p. da oggi, a p. dal prossimo mese*, a cominciare da oggi, dal prossimo mese

La mia domanda sarebbe: c'è qualche ragione per usare "partire" in quella frase? Cioè, sarebbe esattamente la stessa cosa scrivere, per esempio, "è iniziata una tirata" o "è cominciata una tirata"?

---

<sup>1.  Non credo che questa affermazione si corrisponda del tutto con la realtà. Sfogliando il libro di Pasolini, non sono riuscita a trovare nessun "cazzo". A volte appare "c...", però: immagino sia questo. Qualche "stronzo" si trova, ma penso che non siano tanti.</sup>

Comment: Il senso di *tirata* è quello del vocabolario: un monologo senza interruzioni. “Partire* dà un senso di immediatezza o di inizio veemente.

Comment: Grazie, @egreg, ma, per quello che ho spiegato nella domanda, non credo che lo spettacolo teatrale fosse un monologo. Nel terzo link che ho messo si trova l'elenco di tutti gli attori e si vede persino una fotografia che mostra parecchi attori insieme.

Comment: Una "tirata", in senso più ampio, è un discorso forte, magari esacerbato, incentrato su un argomento preciso, oppure lunga. Non deve essere necessariamente un monologo: due genitori, insieme, possono fare una tirata al figlio. Una tirata può anche essere una corsa, a piedi o con un veicolo, in cui durata o velocità sono grandi.

Answer (score 1):

> "tirata" può avere un senso leggermente diverso da quello spiegato dal Treccani?

Il Treccani spiega abbastanza bene il termine, solo che il significato in gergo teatrale avrebbe potuto essere messo *dopo* l'uso che se ne fa in senso generale.

Aggiungo, come ho già fatto nel commento, che "tirata" si può riferire anche ad altre situazioni che il Treccani pare ignorare completamente (non ho controllato). Per esempio:

> Da Roma a Milano è una tirata di sei ore in macchina

indica che il viaggio in macchina dura sei ore, ponendo l'accento sulla lunga durata e sulla continuità senza interruzioni (naturalmente si possono impiegare tre giorni, se si vuole).

Sempre in ambito motoristico o podistico, "tirare" significa provare ad andare velocemente, tirare fuori molto dal motore o dalle gambe, quindi una *tirata* è un tratto di strada o di tempo percorso con gran velocità o grande impegno. Si può applicare anche per esempio a un lavoro, intendendo che portarlo a termine è una faticata.

Se si parla di un discorso, allora una tirata è un discorso lungo, impegnativo, aggressivo, monocorde, magari con intento educativo o, più sovente, critico.

> c'è qualche ragione per usare "partire" in quella frase? ... stessa cosa scrivere "è cominciata una tirata"?

Il senso è lo stesso, ma "partire" è più dinamico e violento. Si dice "è partita una cannonata" (o una bordata,
una fucilata) richiamando il proiettile che parte e lascia l'arma; non è lo stesso dire "è cominciata una fucilata", perché
*partire* indica movimento, *cominciare* no. Il *partire* in quel contesto insinua pure che
il discorso è andato fuori tema, o sopra le righe, o è durato troppo; insomma ha lasciato l'intento originale
perdendosi dietro qualche altra cosa.